# Invariant subspace when $TS=ST$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Assume $S,T: V\to V$ such that $TS=ST$.

Show that if $W\subset V$ is invariant under $T$ then it is also invariant under $S$

I am assuming the problem is trivial however I am a bit stuck.

$T(w_1) \in W$ for all  $w_1$ in $W$, then exists a $w_2$ such that $T(w_2)=w_1$

$S(w_1)=ST(w_2)=TS(w_2)=\space? $

I am missing something completely trivial.. what have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Let $T$ be the identity map. Every $S$ commutes with the identity map and every subspace is invariant under the identity map, and so we find out that every subspace is invariant under every map.

Maybe you got the conditions wrong?

Comment: I think my professor made a mistake, he is teaching in a language that is new to him, could he have meant $S(W)$ invariant under $T$? is that correct?

Comment: "Let $T,S:V\to V$ such that $TS=ST$. Then if $S(W)$ is invariant under $T$ it is also invariant under $S$" makes no sense as a thing to write, and my counterexample still holds. If instead he meant "Let $T,S:V\to V$ such that $TS=ST$. Then if $S(W)$ is invariant under $T$, $T(W)$ is invariant under $S$" the result is totally trivial.

Comment: I suppose he made a translation mistake, I'll ask him in his office hours.
Thank you.